# Generate dates for a particular month?

Tags: python, pandas

is there any way to generate all the dates of a particular month when the month and year are inputted?

I have

```
daterange = date_range(date1, date2)
dates=[]
for x in daterange:
    dates.append((x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

using pandas, but how can I account for different month lengths?

Comment: Have a look at `calendar.monthrange()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find I can't import `calendar` on my system, so here's a `datetime`-only solution:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

month, year = 2, 2008

day = timedelta(days=1)
date1 = date(year, month, 1)
dates = []
d = date1
while d.month == month:
    dates.append(d)
    d += day
```

(Creates a list of the dates of days in February 2008, a leap year). If you want string representations of the dates, you can use:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

month, year = 2, 2008

day = timedelta(days=1)
date1 = datetime(year, month, 1)
d = date1
dates = []
while d.month == month:
    dates.append(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    d += day
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pd.offsets.MonthBegin` and then use an end exclusive daily date range:

```
dts = pd.date_range(month_start, month_start + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1), closed="left")
```

Comment: Note that `month_start` should be a `datetime.datetime`, and not a string. +1 for using `pandas` directly rather than looking for functionality it already has elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the calendar module:

```
import calendar
date_of_first_weekday, number_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
```

Comment: You can leave out the list brackets, tuple unpacking is fine enough without them.

Answer (score 0):

The `calendar` module has all you need:

```
import calendar
first_weekday, month_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
for mday in xrange(1, month_days + 1):
    print mday
```